# How to request for new traffic information using Route Handle (Here Routing API V8)

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, here-routing

Currently I am referring to this document (https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html) and am able to send request to calculate Route by giving route Parameters as shown below:

```
// Get an instance of the routing service version 8:
var router = platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);

//routing parameters
var routingParameters = {
        'routingMode': 'fast',
        'transportMode': 'car',
        // The start point of the route:
        'origin': '52.550028,13.302349',
        // The end point of the route:
        'destination': '58.553272,13.305195',
        // Include the route shape in the response
        'return': 'polyline,typicalDuration,summary,routeHandle'
    };

// Call calculateRoute() with the routing parameters,
// the callback (onResult) and an error callback function (called if a
// communication error occurs):
router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, onResult,
  function(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  });
```

However, if I need to use route handle for updated traffic information for already calculated route, how do i need to request ? Do we have any methods for using route handle like we use calculateRoute method for calculating the new route.

Answer (score 0):

A route handle encodes a previously calculated route. A route can be decoded from a handle as long as the service uses the same map data and encoding that were used when retrieving the handle.

Thus it is suitable for caching routes compactly. It can be used to retrieve updated traffic information or other data along the route. However, a user should be prepared to recalculate the route when decoding the handle fails.

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes/{routeHandle}
```

use route handle to retrieve updated traffic information or other data along the route.

```
traffic
```

object (Traffic)
Traffic specific parameters.

link for more details : https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html